# Python: print("Hola") y @ x,y say'"Hola"

Tags: python

**En Python:**
Existe una función propia de Python o de terceros para imprimir un texto en una posición determinada en la consola/pantalla?

Así como en **foxpro** se utiliza **@ fil,col say"Hola"** para imprimir en una posición de la consola/pantalla.

Comment: No, no existe nada nativo. Pero hay alternativas dependientes del sistema operativo

Comment: A mi el modulo colorama no me funciona. Uno que me funcionó fue el modulo [blessed](https://blessed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/location.html#context-manager). Lo puedes instalar con `pip install blessed`.

Comment: Esta bien el blessed, lo estuve probando. Gracias por la info.